# Failed to load NIF library

Tags: c, erlang

I created a DLL "Addition.dll" where i implemented hello function 
These are the file that i used for the creation of the library: 
main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

//Hello function
static ERL_NIF_TERM hello(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM    argv[])
{
return enif_make_string(env, "Hello world!", ERL_NIF_LATIN1);
}

static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] =
{
 {"hello", 0, hello}
};

ERL_NIF_INIT(niftest,nif_funcs,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

/*************************DLL  Main*******************************************/

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
switch (fdwReason)
{
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // attach to process
        // return FALSE to fail DLL load
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // detach from process
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // attach to thread
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        // detach from thread
        break;
 }
 return TRUE; // successful
}
```

main.h:

```
#define __MAIN_H__
#include <windows.h>
#include <erl_nif.h>

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
/********************************Library   functions******************************/

static ERL_NIF_TERM hello(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM  argv[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

my goal is to call this function using an erlang module so i implemented "niftest.erl" as follow:

```
-module(niftest).
-export([init/0, hello/0]).
-on_load(init/0).

init() ->
  erlang:load_nif("./Addition", 0).

hello() ->
  "NIF library not loaded".
```

and of course put the Addition.dll in the same folder of "niftest.erl" but when i run niftest i have this error

```
4> c(niftest).

=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Apr-2015::11:43:17 ===
The on_load function for module niftest returned {error,
                                              {load_failed,
                                               "Failed to load NIF library    ./Addition.dll: 'Le module spécifié est introuvable.'"}}
{error,on_load_failure}
```

thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 3):

The pathname `"./Addition"` means you're attempting to load the NIF library from the current working directory, and it fails because the NIF is not there. Normally NIF libraries are stored under the application's `priv` directory, and you write code to locate it, something like this:

```
init() ->
    SoName = filename:join(case code:priv_dir(?MODULE) of
                               {error, bad_name} ->
                                   %% this is here for testing purposes
                                   filename:join(
                                     [filename:dirname(
                                        code:which(?MODULE)),"..","priv"]);
                               Dir ->
                                   Dir
                           end, "Addition"),
    erlang:load_nif(SoName, 0).
```

Note the part that handles `{error, bad_name}`: this is handy for development purposes because if the application is not yet installed, this part will find the path to the module trying to load the NIF, assume the `priv` directory is a sibling to its directory, and attempt to load the NIF from there.

Comment: thank you @steve for the answer the error has desapeared however when i run neftist i have this:
2> c(niftest).
{ok,niftest}
3> niftest:hello().
"NIF library not loaded"

that means niftest niftest don't call the function hello of the library "Addition.dll"
what's the problem in your opinion???

Comment: My advice is to export your `init/0` function and try calling it from the shell. You might also consider modifying it temporarily to print the name of the NIF library it's trying to load. For your case, you should also drop the `ok` return at the end of `init/0` and just return the value returned from `erlang:load_nif/2` (I changed my answer to get rid of that `ok`).

Comment: It doesn't work yet i got this error :12> c(niftest).
{ok,niftest}
13> niftest:init().
{error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library c:/Users/achraf/Desktop/NIF_ERLANG/Appel_Dll_Par_Erlang/../priv/Addition: 'Le module spécifié est introuvable.'"}}
note that Addition.dll is in the folder priv,priv is a folder in the project folder

Comment: Is `niftest.beam` in the `c:/Users/achraf/Desktop/NIF_ERLANG/Appel_Dll_Par_Erlang/ebin` folder? If not (and it really should be), but instead it's in `c:/Users/achraf/Desktop/NIF_ERLANG/Appel_Dll_Par_Erlang`, then you need to remove the `".."` string from the `init/0` function.

Comment: In my project folder i have: niftest.erl and priv folder .niftest.BEAM is automatically created in the project folder

Comment: I removed ".." but it doesn't work .
 niftest:init().
{error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library c:/Users/achraf/Desktop/NIF_ERLANG/Appel_Dll_Par_Erlang/priv/Addition: 'Unspecified error'"}}

Comment: Normally `.beam` files are stored in the project's `ebin` directory, and source files like `.erl` are stored in the project's `src` directory. As for the error you're now seeing, I'm not sure as I don't use Windows, but I know on Linux and OS X I typically have to link NIF libraries against the `ei` and `erl_interface` libraries that come with the Erlang distribution for them to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you steve for your reply , I downloaded a project from GitHub https://github.com/vmx/hellonif but still the same error i don't know why

Comment: If you use [`rebar`](https://github.com/rebar/rebar) to build that project, I would think that it would build the NIF properly and would work correctly.

Comment: I linked to it in my previous comment. Also see https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki for information on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the error was that i compiled the dll by x32 platform but i had installed Erl x64.